# Deleting Row in table using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table within a form with a dynamic number of rows that are added by clicking a button to add a new "dummy" row. I put a button at the end of each row that is supposed to delete the corresponding row, but I cannot get the delete button to do anything.
This is the enitre row with the button:

```
<tr id="dummyRow" class="hidden-print" style="display:none">
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><input id="Qty" name="Qty" value="" class="qtyField" type="number" min="0" pattern="[0-9]*" maxlength="6" size="3"></td>
    <td><input id="Price" name="Price" class="PriceField" type="text" maxlength="8" value=""></td>
    <td><input id="Desc" name="Desc" class="hidden" value=""></td>
    <td class="totalCol" taxable="true"></td>           
    <td><button type="button"class="btn btn-xs btn-warning" name="deleteRow"id="deleteRow">X</button></td> 
</tr>
```

And this is the function as I currently have it (which does not work)

```
 $("#deleteRow").click(function() {
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
            tr.remove();
            totalQuote();
          return false;
         });
```

The function is within the $(document).ready(function(){} and the other button to add the rows is in the same function and works fine. I have researched this for an entire day and have tried several different ways to do this but none of them work when the button is within the "dummy row." When it is outside of the row, it works fine, just not within the row.

Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong? I dont know if I am putting the button in the wrong spot or the function in the wrong spot or none of the above

Comment: Isn't the button not accessible when it is inside `display: none`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using this row for clone purposes, than you have to bind future events to that button, and you need to use a class instead of an ID.

To bind and event to all DOM and future ones, which you crate with JS you should use `.on()`

```
$("body").on("click",".deleteRow",callBack);
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you!

Comment: my sincere apologies Burimi, I haven't been on in a while.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is hidden, may be can you try showing it once on screen and removing it?

```js
$(function () {
  $("#deleteRow").click(function() {
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    tr.remove();
    totalQuote();
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr id="dummyRow" class="hidden-print">
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><input id="Qty" name="Qty" value="" class="qtyField" type="number" min="0" pattern="[0-9]*" maxlength="6" size="3"></td>
    <td><input id="Price" name="Price" class="PriceField" type="text" maxlength="8" value=""></td>
    <td><input id="Desc" name="Desc" class="hidden" value=""></td>
    <td class="totalCol" taxable="true"></td>           
    <td><button type="button"class="btn btn-xs btn-warning" name="deleteRow"id="deleteRow">X</button></td> 
  </tr>
</table>
```

Also please try delegating function, if you are using `.clone()` by using `.on()`. And when you give the `.clone()`, please pass the two parameters as `true`:

```
.clone(true, true);
```

This is for cloning the events as well.

Comment: As he said the number of row is dynamic and could be added by clicking a certain button, with this consideration i think this `$("#deleteRow")` won't work, better to pick by the class name..+1

Answer (score 0):

For some reason this is not working on your table code, however check this code within this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n4tg6ouL/3/);

```
$('button.btn').on('click', function () {
    var a = $(this).parent().parent().remove();
    totalQuote();
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

ID's should be unique to a page ["It must be unique to a document"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/id). If you plan on using the `dummy` row multiple times, I suggest placing a class on the button instead and then using event delegation to handle `.delete-row`

Here is a simple example of event delegation:

```js
(function () {
    // Event delegation:
    $('#unique-table-id').on('click', 'button.delete-row', function () {
     $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    });
 
    $('button.add-row').on('click', function () {
        $('#unique-table-id').append($('<tr><td>' + $('#unique-table-id tr').length + '</td><td><button class="delete-row">Delete</button></td></tr>'));
    });
})();
```

```css
table td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

table {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="add-row">Add Row</button>

<table id="unique-table-id"></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Burimi had it exactly right. this function worked perfectly.

```
$("#quoteForm").on("click", ".deleteBtn", function(e) {
            $(this).parent().parent().remove();
        totalQuote();

     });
```

It also worked with `.closest` instead of `.parent().parent()`

Answer (score -1):

Try to add in row `id` a unique value to identify.

```
$('#myTableRow').remove();
```

This works fine, if your row has an `id`, such as:

```
<tr id="myTableRow"><td>blah</td></tr>
```